# 20 Crontab Messages In Order Staggered Every 15 Minutes

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to send messages every 15 minutes.  I have 20 messages, and I want each message to be sent about 15 minutes apart, i.e. message 3 is sent 15 minutes after message 2, message 4 15 minutes after message 3.  Right now I'm just trying to stagger the contab jobs, but is there a more efficient/elegant solution?  Thanks for the help!

```
    14,29,44,59 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message2.php
    13,28,43,58 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message3.php
    12,27,43,57 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message4.php
    11,26,42,56 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message5.php
    10,25,41,55 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message6.php
    9,24,40,55 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message7.php
    8,23,39,54 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message8.php
    7,22,38,53 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message9.php
    6,21,37,52 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message10.php
    5,20,36,51 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message11.php
    4,19,35,50 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message12.php
    3,18,34,49 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message13.php
    2,17,33,48 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message14.php
    1,16,33,47 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message15.php
    0,15,32,46 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message16.php
    14,31,45,59 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message17.php
    13,30,44,58 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message18.php
    12,28,43,57 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message19.php
    11,27,42,56 10-21 * * * wget -q http://site/message20.php
```

Comment: Why not just have one crontab that runs every 15 minutes and then have it touch a single script on the server that determines which of the 20 messages to send.

Comment: Because multiple people are getting the messages at different times (i.e. I might be on message 2, but you're on message 15), so each message needs to be sent around every 15 minutes, but also be sent about 15 minutes apart from the previous message if that makes sense.

Comment: But it would be easier to have a script determine what messages to send out when needed than it would be for cron to figure it out.

Comment: Can you do that with php?  Wouldn't you have to timestamp each message or something in the database, and then check if enough time has passed? Would that be more efficient?

Comment: Well, it could be as simple as storing the user and last message number in a database (or even text file). Each time the script is called, get the last number for each user, increment it, send that new message and increment the number in the database for all users. This is of course not perfect, but better than having a hundred crontabs.

Comment: Hey that makes sense! I might have an idea for how to do that... Although then the server would get slammed every 15 minutes if there are a lot of messages to send...  I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try crontab:
*/15 * * * * wget -q http://site/message.php

Comment: But that would just make every message execute every 15 minutes, potentially sending every message one after the other... which isn't what I want